# PHP Preg_match Matching a class and getting content after

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$str = '<div class="rss"><img src="http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/gadgetlab/2013/10/1125_hbogo_660-660x436.jpg" alt="You Can Now Get HBO GO Without Paying for Other Channels">
</div>Fans of';
```

I'm trying to get hold of the text after the `<div class="rss"></div>` but each expression I use doesn't seem to work.

**matching .rss**

```
if(preg_match('/^(<div class=\"rss\">[\S\s]+?</div>([\S\s]*)$/i', $item_content, $matches)) {
```

Could someone please help with this expression?

Originally I had this expression to match an image tag instead of a div and this worked fine by using

```
if(preg_match('/^(<img[\S\s]+?>)([\S\s]*)$/i', $item_content, $matches)) {
```

Comment: What if there's a `div` inside that `div`? An xpath like `//div[@class="rss"]/following-sibling:text()[1]` seems more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't go deeply for the regex but yours work well with just solving some syntax problems.

It should be:

```
^<div class=\"rss\">[\S\s]+?<\/div>([\S\s]*)$/i
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bT4sK5)

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
<?php
$item_content = '<div class="rss"><img src="http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/gadgetlab/2013/10/1125_hbogo_660-660x436.jpg" alt="You Can Now Get HBO GO Without Paying for Other Channels">
</div>Fans of';

if(preg_match('/^(<div class=\"rss\">[\S\s]+?<\/div>)([\S\s]*)$/i', $item_content, $matches)) {
  $div = $matches[1];
  $text = $matches[2];

  echo "<textarea style=\"width: 600px; height: 300px;\">";
  echo $div . "\n";
  echo $text . "\n";
  echo "</textarea>";
}
?>
```